# Swift generics class for device

Tags: ios, swift, generics

Let's say I got a static function `isDeviceIpad`.
and for any class that supports iPad I got child class with the "_iPad" suffix, and all the iPad logic inside.
And I use `classForDevice` function to get the proper class for my current device like that:

```
static private let iPadClassSuffix = "_iPad"

static func classForDevice() -> AnyClass? {
    var iPadClass: AnyClass?
    let moduleName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleName"] as! String
    let swiftClassName = moduleName+"."+String(describing: self)

    if isDeviceIpad {
        let iPadClassName = swiftClassName+iPadClassSuffix
        iPadClass = Bundle.main.classNamed(iPadClassName)
    }

    return iPadClass ?? Bundle.main.classNamed(swiftClassName)
}
```

Now I want to convert this function to use generics like:
if my class is `MyClass` and my iPad class is `MyClass_iPad`

```
let myClass = MyClass.classForDevice().init(with parameters...)
```

should return instance of `MyClass` for iPhone and instance of `MyClass_iPad` for iPad.
Any suggestions? Maybe using protocols?

Comment: Sounds like a [factory pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method/swift/example) to me

Comment: Why not make `MyClass` and `MyClass_iPad` conform to the same protocol? Then you can call methods and get properties for either one which is stored in memory at the time.

Comment: You need a protocol but not generics as I see it. Create a protocol containing all the public properties and methods in MyClass and declare classForDevice to return that protocol

Comment: Consider: Make MyClassIpad a subclass of MyClass, then when you need to new up a MyClass, have it return either a MyClass or a MyClassIpad depending on the device, but as a MyClass. No need for protocols.

Comment: Given the diversity of the solutions offered in the comments I voted to close this question as opinionated. It’s probably better if you choose one path and try to implement it and then comes back with a new question if you run into any issues.

Answer (score -1):

I've ended up creating a generic class for that:

```
class DeviceHandler<T: AnyObject> {
    static var classForDevice: T.Type {
        var iPadClass: T.Type?
        let iPadClassSuffix = "_iPad"
        let moduleName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleName"] as! String
        let swiftClassName = moduleName+"."+String(describing: T.self)

        if Utils.isDeviceIpad {
            let iPadClassName = swiftClassName+iPadClassSuffix
            iPadClass =  Bundle.main.classNamed(iPadClassName) as? T.Type
        }

        return iPadClass ?? T.self
    }
}
```

Then I use it like:

```
let myClass = DeviceHandler<MyClass>.classForDevice.init(with parameters...)
```

---

EDIT: changed `classForDevice` to be a static variable so I wouldn't need to create instance of DeviceHandler

Comment: This is... pretty strange. (I didn't downvote)

Comment: I would if I could understand a context in which this code snippet makes sense. it's just bizarre. Switching on device type is an anti-pattern in general, and this is just several layers of reflection/complexity on top of that flawed idea

Comment: @Alexander The main idea is to use same logic for different devices with minor cosmetic changes, so for example on the "_iPad" classes you might override behavior like item width for compositional layout, or AlertController presentation style, but keep most of the code structure similar for both devices. I want to avoid checking if `isDeviceIpad` on my classed and instead override behavior on dedicated class

Comment: I get that much, but there's a few issues that I see. For one, You shouldn't really make layout/UI distinctions based on whether a device is an iPad or and iPhone. It's just *wrong*. An iPad app running in Slide Over mode is about as narrow as an iPhone. Any layout decisions you made on the basis that it was an iPad (thinking that iPad = big) would lead to a terrible interface in that mode. The same thing could happen with split screen, or other iPad OS features that might be added in the future

Comment: So maybe the example was wrong but you got differences sometimes, AlertControllers or modal presentations styles for example. maintaining all of this on one class can be messy. I prefer override logic on dedicated subclass, that way you can keep your code clean, and manage all of your device dedicated code on one place. especially when adding iPad support for existing code base.

Comment: I understand the point you're trying to make. I don't disagree that polymorphism is a good way to handle distinctions like this. But I don't think you understood my point, at all. Could you please try re-reading my comments?

Comment: OK, so you're saying I should avoid making UI distinctions right?, and I'm saying that on some scenarios UI distinctions are mandatory. and you think this method might add several layers of reflection/complexity, and I'm saying that I think it makes cleaner code. what is the point you're trying to make you think I've missed?

Comment: No, I’m saying you shouldn’t make UI distinctions based on it being an iPad, specifically. In an ideal world, you’d only use size classes (if you’re using auto-layout), or other *specific* conditions. I.e. the fact that you should show a side bar beside a detail pane isn’t something you should always do because it’s an iPad. You should do it because the window is wide (which is true on a full screen app on an iPad, but not true for iPhones, or iPad apps in split screen or hover-over)

Comment: Agree to some extent, but if for example you'll try to present action sheet on iPad without `popoverPresentationController` you will crash. so like I've said sometimes you got scenarios that are device based. Anyway my question was about generics not cross device development.

Comment: I agree, that looks like a particular case looks like a reasonable case to distinguish iPads from iPhones.